# Using Data Validation in an Embedded Google Sheet in Google Sites

Tags: google-sheets, sites

For a while I have been looking for a way of using Data Validation drop downs in an embedded Google Sheet in Google Sites  . Apparently in Classic sites you could configure the embedded site as a list ( although this didn't work for me at the time ) . However there doesn't seem to be a lot of control in an embedded sheet in the ‘New’ google sites .

Is there a way of allowing someone ( a domain user ) to select something from an embedded sheet in google sites .  The sheet needs to be in a site rather than shared on its own.

Nb. i can use the rm=minimal option in an iframe and that works -  but there is a loading / performance issue with that .

Many thanks in advance